# navbar hover effect above horizontal rule

Tags: html, css

I am designing a new website, and I always spend a lot of time on the navigation bars when I do so. The following code has this intended effect:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
<hr></hr>
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    width: 80%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.navbar a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #c00;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: .35s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works in Chrome, Opera, and even some versions of Internet Explorer, but the other browsers can't agree on anything:

Firefox (and some IE versions):

[image]

Safari:

[image]

here is a code snippet:

```css
hr {
    width: 80%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.navbar a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #c00;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: .35s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
<hr>
```

Is there any way to achieve the intended effect without browser sniffing?

Comment: Did you have reset css in your web page already?
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: nope, I didn't. I just added it and it fixed the problem for firefox, but not safari... That would have been useful to know about when I was designing my own website, thanks!

Comment: I had to look at the provided GIFs for a minute to even see the difference... are you sure this is a difference that really matters? That being said, I would suppose setting the height of the navbar a with line-height instead of padding-top/-bottom will resolve the issue.

Comment: To me, I would set the height to the navbar and the <a> tag in addition to using **box-sizing: border-box;** on all elements (if you use Bootstrap then it should be it now)

Comment: @ToanLu you're solution works consistently between every browser I try and has solved my problem! You can answer if you like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by doing following steps:

- Add reset CSS (could be normalize or Meyer reset CSS)
- Set a specific height to **navbar** and the  element as Safari doesn't do well without the height
- Applying **box-sizing: border-box;** for easy
  styling without much of calculation between padding, border, margin
  within one element.
  Beside, I usually use the border of **navbar** instead of another **hr** tag for the line under the menu